# apache axiom soap client class mediator in EI 6.6.0

Tags: wso2, axis, soap-client, webservice-client, axiom

I have a class mediator as SOAP client using apache axiom libs:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.ws.commons.axiom</groupId>
    <artifactId>axiom-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.22</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.ws.commons.axiom</groupId>
    <artifactId>axiom-impl</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.22</version>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.ws.commons.axiom</groupId>
    <artifactId>axiom-dom</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.22</version>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

Locally the code works as a java application.

But I'm getting the following error when I try to run it in my EI 6.6.0 through an API:

```
javax.xml.soap.SOAPException: Unable to create SOAP connection factory: com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.client.p2p.HttpSOAPConnectionFactory cannot be cast to javax.xml.soap.SOAPConnectionFactory
```

Comment: please, anyone ?

Comment: Can you share the section of code in which you are getting this error? Can you also share the java version you are using?